# How to reload report with same parameters in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing, reload, ssrs-2012

Scenario - I have a multi-value visible (user defined) parameter that I use in the dataset query, and I have a link in the report that directs the user to the same report (but it does something else that is irrelevant to this topic). However, when the report reloads, the user has to set the parameter again from the drop-down list.

Question - Is there a possibility to pass the parameter that the user already set the first time, and reload the report without forcing the user to set it again?

What I tried so far (with no success) - I tried passing the following parameter values to the report:

- Parameters!param_name.Value(0)
- param_name
- [param_name]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is - Yes, it's possible.

Have you tried - "=Parameters!param_name.Value" without "(0)" ?

Go to the Action tab of the Text Box Properties, select "Go to report" as Action, specify your current report as the destination report. And choose the parameters.

It works.

[image: Text Box Properties window]